# saveas in *.xps format of xml document

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have an xml document which is from email. I want to save as dialogue box in my desktop in .xps format of that xml document in C# .net with Windows application.

Comment: Do you want to see the raw XML, or do you want to interpret the XML as some form of document?

Comment: Hello, I want to view the format data that means the data inside the xml.

Comment: @user I don't understand. Do you want to see the same as if you opened it in Notepad?

Comment: yes..same as i can view it in Notepad

Comment: @user do you want any syntax highlighting?

Comment: No Sir, only the document should be save as in .xps format

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the XML attachment with Internet Explorer, and from there you can save it as .xps by printing the document using the Windows XPS printer.

Comment: Dunno have "the code". Just implement it step by step as I said. Outlook has a API. And I bet the Windows XPS writer also has one.